# 2D Array Middle Point

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Given dimensions of a 2D array, except **1xn**, that results in an odd number of elements, find the midpoint index.

Example: Input is **3x5**, representing the 2D array

> [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4]
>
> [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [1,4]
>
> [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4]

The midpoint index is **[1,2]**

#### Input

> **3**
>
> **5**

#### Output

> **1 , 2**

#### Rules

- Standard code-golf rules, fewest bytes wins
- Either full program or function is permitted
- When input is either **1xn** or the corresponding array would have an even number of elements, *output must be* **[0,0]**
- **nx1** should be treated like any other array

Comment: Most challenges on PPCG try to avoid special cases or error cases, instead guaranteeing that the input will be valid. It's your call to make, but I find that error handling is usually boilerplate that makes solutions longer without making them more interesting.

Comment: We have a [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1).

Comment: @EsolangingFruit The challenge here *is* to handle the invalid inputs, otherwise it would trivially be ⁽ⁿ⁻²⁾⁄₂.

Comment: @Adám A challenge where the entire point is to detect and handle invalid inputs doesn't seem like a very interesting challenge to me.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit There's nothing inherently wrong with challenges that a specific user happens to find uninteresting. Personally, I think having to catch such specific cases makes for some interesting golfing material.

Comment: @NoirAntares I've edited your challenge to make it unambiguous. Feel free to [edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/167872/edit) or [roll back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/167872/revisions) If my rewording does not match your intentions.

Comment: @JoKing Well, [⁽ⁿ⁻²⁾⁄₂,0], yeah.

Comment: `output must be [0,0]` any reason behind that? How does that part add anything to computing the midpoint? Obviously, 1xn arrays or arrays with an even dimension don't have `[0,0]` as their midpoints.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```apl
⌊÷∘2×2|×/×1≠⊃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/04Dko56uw9sfdcwwOjzdqObwdP3D0w0fdS541NX8/3@agrGCqcKj3rkKeflFuYk5XGlAriFEQDepUtcQKGAIVWEIEsgDCphABVLLUvMU8kpzk1KLFPLTFIryy4u5QAaaYJNNzs8pzc0rBms3w6VdITEvBaYSAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

My first (somewhat) serious Japt submission! Any help is appreciated, I think ~10 bytes or even less may be possible. Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)!

```
£ÎÉ©Ueu)*Xz
```

[Try it here!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o87JqVVldSkqWHo=&input=WwpbMTcsMjldClsxNywxXQpbMSwxN10KWzMsNV0KWzMsNF0KXQotbVI=)

#### How it works

*Slightly outdated.*

```
£eu *UÎ>1 *Xz – Full program.
£             – For each X of the input array.
          *Xz – Multiply floor(X/2) by the truth value of:
 eu           – Are both numbers odd? And...
    *UÎ>1     – Is the initial element greater than 1?
              – Implicit output to STDOUT.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous prefix function. Takes rows,columns as right argument.

```apl
{0::0 0⋄÷∘÷@0⌽¨⍨.5×⍵-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sNrKwMFAwedbcc3v6oY8bh7Q4Gj3r2HlrxqHeFnunh6Y96t@oa1v5PA6p91NsH0dbVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@n6ZgrGCqoPCod65CXn5RbmIOVxqQbwgV0U2q1DUEihjC1BiCRPKAIiYwkdSy1DyFvNLcpNQihfw0haL88mIukKEmWKWT83NKc/OKwQaY4TRAITEvBawUpBYA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; `⍵` is right argument (rightmost letter of Greek alphabet).

`0::` if any error happens:

`0 0` return `[0,0]`

`⋄` now try:

`⍵-1` right argument minus 1

`.5×` multiply by a half

`⌽¨⍨` rotate each by itself (this errors on non-integers)

`÷∘÷@0` reciprocal of reciprocal at position 0 (this errors when the first coordinate is 0)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Mr. Xcoder* (remove `D`)

```
¬≠*ÉP*;ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0JpHnQu0DncGaFkfXv//f7SxjoJpLAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVqns8v/QmkedC7QOdwZoWR9e/79S6fB@BV07hcP7lXT@GyuYcpkqGAOxIZchkG2kYMJlomAEpM25zIG0gYIBAA)

**Explanation**

```
¬≠*       # multiply the input by its first value falsified
   ÉP*    # multiply the input by the product of the results values' oddness
      ;   # divide by 2
       ï  # convert to int
```

Comment: Nice!  I had `¬≠sPÉ*s2÷*` for 10 bytes. Taking some inspiration from you though, would `¬≠*PÉ*2÷` [work](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVqns8v/QmkedC7QCDndqGR3e/r9S6fB@BV07hcP7lXT@GyuYcpkqGAOxIZchkG2kYMJlomAEpM25zIG0gYIBAA) for 8 bytes? Alternatively, `¬≠*PÉ*;ï`, of course.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Of course. I don't need the `D` here :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>24</s> 16 bytes

*-8 bytes saved thanks to @Shaggy*

```
Neu ©UÉ?Nmz :2ÆT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3y@1VOHQytDDnfZ@uVUKVkaH20L@/zc01zGyBAA)

Comment: You can get this down to [16 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TmV1IKlVyT9ObXogOjLGVA==&input=MTcsMjk=) with a few tricks, mainly making use of the `N` variable.

Comment: Feel free to ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt) if you've any questions.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil*

Takes the dimensions in currying syntax `(w)(h)`.

```javascript
w=>h=>w&h&w>1?[h>>1,w>>1]:[0,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/c1i7D1q5cLUOt3M7QPjrDzs5QpxxIxFpFG@gYxP5Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI0zDV1DDW1ORCFTTW1DDEEASqNMEQNNTUMMImCDTzPwA)

---

## Original version, 32 bytes

Takes the dimensions in currying syntax `(w)(h)`.

```javascript
w=>h=>w*h&!!--w?[h>>1,w/2]:[0,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/c1i7D1q5cLUNNUVFXt9w@OsPOzlCnXN8o1iraQMcg9n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmmhrGmJheqoLGmhiGGIFClCYagoaaGETZBoJn/AQ)

#### How?

We want to test whether both \$w\$ and \$h\$ are odd, which is true if and only if \$w\times h\$ is odd. We also want to make sure that \$w\$ is not equal to \$1\$, which means that \$w-1\$ is not equal to \$0\$. We can merge both tests into:

```javascript
w * h & !!--w
```

If this test passes, we know that \$w\$ was odd and is now even (since it was decremented), so we can divide it by \$2\$ with a standard division. For \$h\$, we use a bitwise shift instead because it's still odd.

Comment: `w=>h=>w&h&w>1?[h>>1,w>>1]:[0,0]`?

Comment: @Neil This is a bit more straightforward indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```perl6
{(^$^a X ^$^b)[$b-1&&$a*$b%2&&$a*$b/2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ojTiUuUSFCAUglaUarJOkaqqmpJGqpJKkaQRn6RrG1/4sTKxXSNAx1DDWtuWBsYzjbGEncWMcUzjZCYZtoWv8HAA)

Anonymous code block that returns a list of two integers.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                     }  # Anonymous code block
 (^$^a X ^$^b)   # Cross product of the two ranges, basically the flattened 2D array
              [                      ] # Get the element at
                            &&$a*$b/2    # Midpoint of the array
                     $a*$b%2             # If the numbers are odd
               $b-1&&                    # And the second element is not 1
                                        # Else the 0th element, which is 0,0
```

Comment: Seems to fail on 7×1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pF0TZawyFeIULXUDNC3yjW2kChokJRo7g0FyQapWqkqRatFatQo6KoqWVUA6Rq/xcnViqkaZjrGGpa/wcA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm confused. Why is 1xn expected to fail, but nx1 is fine?

Comment: Because OP says so.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>This confused me :p</sup>

```
:2×Ḃ_ỊḢ$PƲ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of the dimensions returning a list of the middle-indices or `[0,0]` in the special-cases.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//OjLDl@G4gl/hu4rhuKIkUMay////WzEsMTld)**

#### How?

```
:2×Ḃ_ỊḢ$PƲ - Link: list of dimension lengths        e.g.  [19,12]  or  [19,13]  or  [1,19]  or  [19,1]
:2        - integer divide by two (gets middle indices)   [9,6]         [9,6]       [0,9]       [9,0]
        Ʋ - last four links as a monad:
   Ḃ      -   bit (n%2) (of the input)                    [1,0]         [1,1]       [1,1]       [1,1]
       $  -   last two links as a monad (of the input):
     Ị    -     insignificant? (abs(n)<=1)                [0,0]         [0,0]       [1,0]       [0,1]
      Ḣ   -     head                                      0             0           1           0
    _     -   subtract (vectorises)                       [1,0]         [1,1]       [0,0]       [1,1]
       P  -   product                                     0             1           0           1
  ×       - multiply (vectorises)                         [0,0]         [9,6]       [0,0]       [9,0]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>46</strike> 42 bytes

```hs
x%y|odd$x*y,x>1=(`div`2)<$>[x,y]|1<2=[0,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0K1siY/JUWlQqtSp8LO0FYjISWzLMFI00bFLrpCpzK2xtDGyDbaQMcg9n9uYmaegq1CSj6XgkKFgo2uQnpqiU9mXiqQW4nKLSjKzCtRUFHQKEpNTAGqtbJS8Mwr0VRQhYpUwkX@G3OZAgA)

*EDIT: -4 bytes thanks to a trick from [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s answer.*

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <strike>28</strike> 27 bytes

```julia
x\y=x&y&1&(x>1)*[x÷2,y÷2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxDYAgEEDRVajInTmLA9FKpqBDCkqNGmM0gckcwMEQm/eLv9zrHPtS0pTHJLNkCckyNj69j6JcCWWLB7jWHue8X@sOznOYnFcBSYAAJsNIoKirajJVQ7rKPfF/ePiLKMoH)

*(-1 byte thanks to Jo King.)*

Explanation:

`x\y` - define an operator instead of a function, to save bytes
`x&y&1` - check that both inputs are odd.
`&(x>1)` - and that the first input is not 1
`*` - the result of the above checks is 0 or 1, multiply that with:
`[x÷2,y÷2]` - `÷` is integer division, so here for odd numbers gives `(n-1)/2` i.e. the middle index. So this forms a vector of the two middle indices (which might be made `[0, 0]` if any of the previous checks fail).

Comment: I don't know Julia, but could you assign to a one byte operator instead, like [`+`](https://tio.run/##FcmxDYAgEEDRVajInZ7FgWglU9ARCkuMGmM0gckcwMEQm/eLv9xrnIdSUpunJLNkCckyNj69j6JcCWWbD3CdPc64X@sOznNonVcBSYAAJsNIoKivajJVQ7rKA/F/ePyLKMoH)?

Comment: Short answer: Yes thank you! Long answer: Your comment finally prompted me to check why those work on TIO but not on my system (I'd assumed it was just version differences). Turns out [I can assign to those if I haven't used them yet in that session](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9547#issuecomment-68551362). Makes some confusing behaviour around this make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

<sup><sub>*Ugh. Waaaaaaaay too long!*</sub></sup>

```
:2×ḂẠ$×Ḣn1Ɗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/K6PD0hzuaHu5aoAJiLMozPNb1/3D7o6Y1//9HRxvqmBrG6kQb6ZgASWMdUyBpqmMMJA3NdAxBMoaWOobGsbEA)

#### Alternative, 11 bytes

```
ḷ/>1×ḂẠ$×:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju36doaHpz/c0fRw1wKVw9OtjP4fbn/UtOb//@hoQx1Tw1idaCMdEyBprGMKJE11jIGkoZmOIUjG0FLH0Dg2FgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 77 bytes

```lua
x,y=...f=math.floor print((x%2==1 and y%2==1)and f(x/2)..","..f(y/2)or "0,0")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/QqfSVk9PL802N7EkQy8tJz@/SKGgKDOvREOjQtXI1tZQITEvRaESzNQEMdM0KvSNNPX0lHSUgNo0KoEcoBYlAx0DJc3///@b/7f8DwA)

not the smallest language but submission for practicing :)

Comment: I don't know much Lua (although I wish I did!), but I believe you can replace the oddness check `x%2==1 and y%2==1` with `x%2+y%2>1` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/QqfSVk9PL802N7EkQy8tJz@/SKGgKDOvREOjQtVIu1LVyM5QMzEvRSFNo0LfSFNPT0lHCahcoxLIASpVMtAxUNL8//@/@X9LAA "Lua – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, this doesn't return `0,0` when `x` is 1, which is one of the question's requirements

Comment: You can extend the condition to check that too, here's my attempt: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/QqfSVk9PL802N7EkQy8tJz@/SKGgKDOvRKNCq1LVSDtNo0LfSNPOUCExL0UBwtHTU9JRAmrRqARygMqVDHQMlDT///9v@N/yPwA "Lua – Try It Online") (also changed `x%2+y%2` to `x*y%2` after seeing Arnauld's answer.)

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything in Lua, but it has the `//` operator yes? So you don't need the floor function

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```rust
|w,h|if w>1&&w*h%2>0{(w/2,h/2)}else{(0,0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jczRCoMgGIbh813Fv2Ch44fUrZNi7VoGMxTMohwemNfu2hg7ze/4/Z75tbjUWxge2hIK4QDbjHQw6Oc0auvgllaPatU9@I6XpT@rk@hYIL4SqCpBozSLDIQhozF93u3XmObtbOyRFKG5xwL/IOEINaV7lUAQWVWGdUG4ZlV5Ft@v6p8V0xs)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

An extra byte removed thanks to @Guiseppe

```r
(i=scan()-1)/2*!any(i%%2,!i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XyPTtjg5MU9DU9dQU99ISzExr1IjU1XVSEcxU/O/oYLpfwA)

Get the input, subtract 1 store in `i` and divide by 2 and multiply by not any evens or 0's in `i`

Comment: `!i` instead of `i<2`?

Comment: @Giuseppe good call, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to ovs

```python
lambda a,b:[0,a/2,0,b/2][a>1==a*b%2::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvYxvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kq2kAnUd9Ix0AnSd8oNjrRztDWNlErSdXIysoo9n9BUWZeiYKPhqGOpaUmF4xnrGOI4Jgjc4x1TJE5JgiOEVDmPwA)

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvYxvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kq2kAnUd9Ix0AnSd8oNjrRztDWNlErSdXIysoo9n9BUWZeiYKPhqGOpaUmF4xnrGOI4Jgjc4x1TJE5JgiOEVDmPwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:((0,0),(a/2,b/2))[a*b%2*(a>1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoMwEIXhqwyFwkQHzMTagqAXSQOZUEKFNoq4SE@fxs33L97bfsd7TabE6Vk@8g0vAaEwImrSilA6Q6EzSllpwtU0KDMrV@K6Q4YlATINXH@GbtWehupAfZXvxOfCj7Pjti/pAJ89tHCBaa604CNmqx1ly0758gc)

No rocket science here.

-2 with thanks to @MrXcoder and @Emigna

Comment: `[a*b%2*(a!=1)]` should work for 42 bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: or even `a>1`.